# Why do I have to specify all parameters for wp_enqueue_script to load my jquery in the footer?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', includes_url() . 'js/jquery.js', array(''), '1.7.2', true); // loads in the footer

wp_enqueue_script('jquery','', array(''), '', true); // loads in the head
```

I just think it seems like backwards development to have to include a non-null value for each parameter to get the script to load where I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that is the signature of that particular function. If you don't like it, you can always use a wrapper function like the one below.

```
function wpse61783_enqueue_script( $handle, $src ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, array(), '', true );
}
```